# Can I use this spray gun with my air compressor?

Tags: compressor, spraying, spraypainting

I have a spray gun that needs 4.4 cfm and 60 psi to work. My compressor is only 2.6 cfm but 135psi with a 6 gallon tank and a 2hp engine. Will this setup work to spray paint?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using an automotive sprayer. You need to set your compressor's regulator to **60 PSI max** or the can may explode. If the compressor doesn't have an adjustable regulator, you'll need to install one.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine until the tank runs low. Then you go and refill your coffee until the compressor catches up.